# Show cols on slider on mobile view

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

Use vuejs 2 and bootstrap.

i have row with 3 cols.

```
.row
.col-xl-4
.col-xl-4
.col-xl-4
```

On mobile view the page gets very long.  My idea is put this col in slider so the user can swipe on mobile device.

What is the best approach in this?  if then statement ?

best remco

Comment: Use flex and wrap them

Comment: thanks arezou...can you give a example? :)